# Bridge an outbound call to a conference with freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch, bridge, conference

I am new to FreeSWITCH and now I`m trying to do something:

1. I will issue an originate with fs_cli to make an outbound call to
   user agent 1017.
2. 1017 will ring and the call will be answered.
3. 1017 will redirect to a specified conference.

What should the originate looks like? Do I need to use sofia in the originate?

Answer (score 3):

you need to use one of the scripting language at your choice: Lua, perl, javascript, python. You can also program this behavior through the event socket library. This book will save you a lot of time and will let you use the system efficiently: https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/freeswitch-12

Comment: So,you mean I can not implement it with just a originate invoke,right?I have the book,should I master chapter 7(Dialplan scripting with lua)?

Comment: yep, lua or other scripting language will give you must flexibility. But you can also run the originate command from CLI and use `&conference(NAME)` at the end. That should work.

Comment: You can also use "conference dial" command and dial out from the conference. See https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_conference#dial

Comment: you see, there are multiple ways to do the thing, and you need to choose the one that fits your requirements. With a script, you can, for example, request the callee to confirm the call with DTMF, and then brodge into the conference.

Comment: Thanks you for offer me so much solution:)I pick the easiest one using &conference().